# Unable to load font for use with ImageSharp in Xamarin Android app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, imagesharp

I have a Xamarin Forms app where I've included a font file called `Roboto-Regular.ttf` in the **Assets** folder of the Android project. Its Build Action is set to `AndroidAsset`.

Using the `SixLabors.Fonts` NuGet package, I'm trying to load this font to use it for watermarking.

However, trying to install the font using the asset stream, an exception is thrown saying:

> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.

```
var fonts = new FontCollection();

FontFamily fontFamily;

using (var fontStream = Assets.Open("Roboto-Regular.ttf"))
{
    fontFamily = fonts.Install(fontStream); // Fails with "method not supported"
}

return fontFamily;
```

Any ideas what might be causing this, or if there is a better way to load fonts for use with the `SixLabors.ImageSharp` package?

**Edit:** I tried the suggestion below by SushiHangover, but it yields the same result:

[image: Android asset stream in Xamarin]

Comment: Did you use appropriate build action for Roboto-Regular.ttf file?

Comment: Yes, it's set to `AndroidAsset`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the underlying `Stream` did not have `Length` or `Position` properties (which explains the exception), so for now I resorted to converting to a seekable `MemoryStream` instead:

```
using (var assetStreamReader = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("Roboto-Regular.ttf"))
{   
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        assetStreamReader.BaseStream.CopyTo(ms);

        ms.Position = 0;

        var fontFamily = new FontCollection().Install(ms);
    }
}
```

Looking at the `FontReader` implementation, the error now makes even more sense: https://github.com/SixLabors/Fonts/blob/master/src/SixLabors.Fonts/FontReader.cs

However, I'm not sure why `Assets` doesn't return a seekable stream?

Comment: `...I'm not sure why Assets doesn't return a seekable stream?...` There is one, review my answer....

Answer (score 0):

There is are two `Assets.Open` methods and one provides an `accessMode` (C# Access enum flag set):

```
using (var fontStream = Assets.Open("Roboto-Regular.ttf", Android.Content.Res.Access.Random))
{
    fontFamily = fonts.Install(fontStream); 
}
```

re: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open(java.lang.String,%20int)

```
public enum Access
{
    [IntDefinition (null, JniField = "android/content/res/AssetManager.ACCESS_BUFFER")]
    Buffer = 3,
    [IntDefinition (null, JniField = "android/content/res/AssetManager.ACCESS_RANDOM")]
    Random = 1,
    [IntDefinition (null, JniField = "android/content/res/AssetManager.ACCESS_STREAMING")]
    Streaming,
    [IntDefinition (null, JniField = "android/content/res/AssetManager.ACCESS_UNKNOWN")]
    Unknown = 0
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't produce a seekable stream it seems (I've edited my OP to clarify).